# How can I upload .ev3 files to my brick under macOS Catalina

Tags: ev3, software, mac, ios

After updating my Mac to macOS Catalina I can no longer run the previous Mindstorms software. The new tool "Mindstorms Home" doesn't allow for opening .ev3 files and uploading them to the brick.
Does anyone know of another way to upload the contents of .ev3 files to the EV3 brick?
Via the Mac or via iOS perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to compile a .ev3 file to a .rbf file is with the "EV3 Lab" software that is not compatible with macOS 10.15 Catalina.

So your options are:

1. Run Windows or an older version of macOS in a virtual machine, such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
2. Find someone that can send you the compiled .rbf file, then use a tool such as [ev3duder](https://github.com/c4ev3/ev3duder) to transfer the program to the EV3.
3. Write a new program in the new scratch-based programming software.